# Can i pause the CCAnimation?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to pause and resume action applied to the ccSprite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654468/how-to-pause-and-resume-action-applied-to-the-ccsprite)

I am new to box2d. I am using CCAnimation, It working fine but i want to pause the animation in meantime. Is it passable?

```
[mySprite runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim]]];
```

Any help me...

Comment: Check this url :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654468/how-to-pause-and-resume-action-applied-to-the-ccsprite